# ModelEntity.load from url

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile, augmented-reality

I have a screen with AR, at the moment .usdz 3D models are stored locally in the application, we need to make sure that they are received using get request.

Here is url to check: https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/models/vintagerobot2k/robot_walk_idle.usdz

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import FocusEntity

struct ARScreen : View {
    @StateObject var selectedVerb = globalVerb()
    
    @State private var isPlacementEnabled = false
    @State private var selectedModel = "sitdown.usdz"//: String?
    @State private var modelComfiredForPlacement: String?
    
    init() {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationController()
        navBarAppearance.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes=[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:
        UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .black
    }
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                ARViewContainer(modelConfirmedForPlacement: self.$modelComfiredForPlacement)
                
                PlacementButtonView(isPlacementEnabled: self.$isPlacementEnabled, selectedModel: self.selectedModel, modelComfirmedForPlacement: self.$modelComfiredForPlacement)
            }.background(Color("Yellow").ignoresSafeArea())
        }.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
        
        
        
    }
    
    struct ARViewContainer: UIViewRepresentable {
        
        @Binding var modelConfirmedForPlacement: String?
        
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
            
            let arView = CustomARView(frame: .zero)//ARView(frame: .zero)
            
            return arView
            
        }
        
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) {
            if let modelName = self.modelConfirmedForPlacement {
                print("Debug: adding model to scene")
                
                let fileName = modelName + ".usdz"
                
                
                
                let modelEntity = try! ModelEntity.load(named: "\(UserDefaults().value(forKey: "verb")!).usdz")
                
                let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .any)
                anchorEntity.addChild(modelEntity)
                
                uiView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
                
                modelEntity.playAnimation(modelEntity.availableAnimations[0].repeat(),
                                          transitionDuration: 0.5,
                                                startsPaused: false)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.modelConfirmedForPlacement = nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    class CustomARView: ARView, FEDelegate {
        let focusSquare = FESquare()
        
        required init(frame frameRect: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frameRect)
            
            focusSquare.viewDelegate = self
            focusSquare.delegate = self
            focusSquare.setAutoUpdate(to: true)
        
            self.setupARView()
        }
        func setupARView() {
            let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
            config.planeDetection = [.horizontal, .vertical]
            config.environmentTexturing = .automatic
            if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsSceneReconstruction(.mesh) {
                config.sceneReconstruction = .mesh
            }
            self.session.run(config)
        }
        @MainActor required dynamic init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
}

struct PlacementButtonView: View {
    
    @Binding var isPlacementEnabled: Bool
    var selectedModel: String?
    @Binding var modelComfirmedForPlacement: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Debug: Confirm model")
            self.modelComfirmedForPlacement = self.selectedModel
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                .font(.title)
                .background(Color.white.opacity(0.75))
                .cornerRadius(30)
                .padding(20)
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ARScreen()
    }
}
#endif
```

I tried to solve this problem with
[RealityKit – Load ModelEntity from web URL resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936194/realitykit-load-modelentity-from-web-url-resource) But nothing came of it

Comment: I need to load model from url

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Json Parse Error line 22: Json Deserialization; unknown member 'EnableGuidedFilterOcclusion' - skipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307832/json-parse-error-line-22-json-deserialization-unknown-member-enableguidedfilt)